# Returning a Boolean Value in VBA

Tags: excel, boolean, worksheet-function, vba

I have a piece of code that is supposed to check for the presence of a sheet by name.  If the sheet exists, there are some copy and past functions, if the sheet does no exist, then it will create of and the same copy past functions will follow.  I cannot get the correct boolean value to return to the main sub.  The boolean value is always registering as false (which I know is the default value).  I have tried several different methods to correct the issue and I am still having problems.  I could really use some help, it is probably an easy fix.

```
Sub BreakOutCategories()

    Dim catSheet As Worksheet
    Dim catName As String
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim gRange As Range
    Dim toSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CheckSheet As Boolean
    Dim CreateSheet As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

        Set catSheet = Sheets("MasterList")
        Set Range1 = catSheet.Range("A1", catSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

            For Each gRange In Range1

            i = 0
            catName = gRange.Value

            CheckMySheet (catName)

                If CheckSheet = True Then

                    toSheet = Sheets(gRange.Value)

                    gRange.Offset(0, 1).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("A1", toSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste
                    gRange.Offset(0, 1).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("E1", toSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste

                    gRange.Offset(0, 2).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("B1", toSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste
                    gRange.Offset(0, 2).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("F1", toSheet.Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste

                ElseIf CheckSheet = False Then

                    CreateMySheet catName

                    toSheet = (gRange.Value)

                    gRange.Offset(0, 1).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("A1", toSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste
                    gRange.Offset(0, 1).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("E1", toSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste

                    gRange.Offset(0, 2).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("B1", toSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste
                    gRange.Offset(0, 2).Copy
                    toSheet.Range("F1", toSheet.Range("F1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Paste

                End If

            Next gRange

End Sub
Public Function CheckMySheet(ByVal catName As String) As Boolean

    Dim theSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CheckSheet As Boolean

        For Each theSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

            If theSheet.Name = catName Then

                CheckSheet = True
                Exit For

            End If

        Next theSheet

End Function
Public Function CreateMySheet(ByVal catName As String) As Boolean

    Dim catSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim gRange As Range

        Set catSheet = Sheets("MasterList")
        Set Range1 = catSheet.Range("A1", catSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Cover"))
        newSheet.Name = catName

        newSheet.Range("A1") = "Line"
        newSheet.Range("E1") = "Line"
        newSheet.Range("B1") = "Item"
        newSheet.Range("F1") = "Item"
        newSheet.Range("C1") = "Units"
        newSheet.Range("G1") = "Sales"

        CreateMySheet = True

End Function
```

I've posted the code in it's entirety to try and give a good picture of what I am trying to accomplish.  I was also considering a `Do Until` loop after `CreateMySheet catName` to check for the presence of the sheet again to prevent the code from moving forward until the sheet has been fully created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you will still need to improve your copying and pasting, but to get you started with the sheet creation here is some of your code modified to do create a new sheet if it doesnt exist in the list

```
Option Explicit

Sub BreakOutCategories()

    Dim catSheet As Worksheet
    Dim catName As String
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim gRange As Range
    Dim toSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CheckSheet As Boolean
    Dim CreateSheet As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    Set catSheet = Sheets("MasterList")
    Set Range1 = catSheet.Range("A1", catSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    For Each gRange In Range1
        i = 0
        catName = gRange.Value
        If CheckMySheet(catName) Then
            Set toSheet = Sheets(gRange.Value)
            ' sheet exists do your copying
        Else
            CreateMySheet catName
            Set toSheet = Sheets(gRange.Value)
            ' sheets didnt exist
        End If
    Next gRange
End Sub

Private Function CheckMySheet(ByVal catName As String) As Boolean
    Dim theSheet As Worksheet
    For Each theSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(theSheet.Name, catName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            CheckMySheet = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next theSheet
End Function

Private Function CreateMySheet(ByVal catName As String) As Boolean
    Dim catSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Range1 As Range
    Dim gRange As Range

    Set catSheet = Sheets("MasterList")
    Set Range1 = catSheet.Range("A1", catSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Cover"))
    newSheet.Name = catName

    newSheet.Range("A1") = "Line"
    newSheet.Range("E1") = "Line"
    newSheet.Range("B1") = "Item"
    newSheet.Range("F1") = "Item"
    newSheet.Range("C1") = "Units"
    newSheet.Range("G1") = "Sales"

    CreateMySheet = True
End Function
```

**UPDATE**:
Further to your comments I think you need to read a bit more about functions and how they work. It's relatively easy and definitely basic stuff you need to learn if you planning on coding/programming. I can recommend [Pearsons Guide](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx) as a starting point. 
Now, let me show you the easiest of easy examples 
 Make sure you know what the **difference between a `function` and `procedure` is before you move on**.

```
Function ReturnTrue() As Boolean
    ReturnTrue = True
End Function

Function ReturnFalse() As Boolean
    ReturnFalse = False
End Function
```

The above demonstrates how to return a Boolean value from a function with no criteria. If you call that from a module one will always return true and other always false.

the below demonstrates how to return a Value from a function based on some criteria. This time you want to `RUN` the `BooleanFunctions()` to better understand the code and the results. I hope this helps

```
Function TrueOrFalse(number As Integer) As Boolean
    If number > 0 And number < 255 Then
        TrueOrFalse = True
    Else
        TrueOrFalse = False
    End If
End Function

Sub BooleanFunctions()
    Dim functionResult As Boolean
    functionResult = TrueOrFalse(10)
    MsgBox functionResult
    functionResult = TrueOrFalse(-10)
    MsgBox functionResult
End Sub
```

As you can see there value that is going to be returned by function is the functions name and whatever is assigned to it as the last call in a function

Comment: Thanks mehow! You're correct on the copy/past stuff, I will start refining that now, but it got me to that point at least.  I know this is not a classroom per se, but what is it exactly that needs to be done to return a boolean value properly?

Answer (score 1):

You never set the value of the function so, as you note, it returns the default value of `False`. Fix it by adding a line at the end:

```
Public Function CheckMySheet(ByVal catName As String) As Boolean

    Dim theSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CheckSheet As Boolean

        For Each theSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If theSheet.Name = catName Then
                CheckSheet = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next theSheet

CheckMySheet = CheckSheet 

End Function
```

Comment: The first 3 items in the "MasterList" are "STEERING".  I set breakpoints at `If CheckSheet = True Then` and at `If CheckSheet = False Then` It created the STEERING sheet the first time through like it should.  The second time through it should see the sheet, CheckSheet should return true, and it should only try to copy and paste.  Instead CheckSheet is still returning false, even after I added `CheckMySheet = CheckSheet` to the end of the CheckMySheet Function.